How can I handle invalid data type exception and stop program execution?
I have a problem, I am studying exceptions and apparently I misunderstood something.
int n;
try {
  cout << "enter value: " << endl;
  cin >> n;
}
catch (exception& ex) {
  cerr << ex.what();
}
cout << n;

Output for any character literal:
Output of the literal itself and zero.
I want to understand, if the user enters the wrong data type, can I somehow handle this input with an exception and tell the user that he is entering text, not a number?
How can I understand where the exception throw occurs?
How can I stop the program execution with the help of processing, otherwise the program continues to execute instructions...
I entered a non-numeric value and expected the program to tell me about it. I expected the program to stop executing after that.
also i tried this code
cout << "enter value: " << endl;
cin >> n;
if (!cin) throw exception();
try {
    cout << n;
}
catch (exception& ex) {
    cerr << ex.what();
}


The throw has to be inside the try {   } for it to be caught. And no, cin doesn't normally throw for invalid input, instead it stops reading and sets an error condition for itself.

A "character literal" is something you write in your source code: 'a', for example. Presumably the input that's giving trouble is a non-digit character.

Side note: there's no need for that std::endl after the prompt. std::cout and std::cin are tied; the stream extractor (std::cin >> n) first flushes std::cout, so the prompt will be displayed without forcing it.

Re: "entering text, not a number" -- all user input is text, not a number. The problem is that the text begins with a non-digit character, so it can't be converted to a number.

The usual route here doesn't involve exceptions. Just loop until the input is valid: while (!std::cin >> n) { /* clean up and prompt for new input */ }.

you should check for error in code that is inside try block.
based on your code ( looks like you are using std and endl)
the code will be :
try {
    std::cout << "Enter value \n";
    std::cin >> value;
    if(std::cin.fail())
       throw (/*what ever error you want*/);
    /*
     or 
     if(std::cin.fail())
       throw std::invalid_argument("your error text");
    */

}
catch(const char *e){
    std::cerr << "ERROR " << e << '\n';
    std::cin.clear();
    // send user to try for new input as you want
}
/*
catch(const std::invalid_argument &err)
{
    std::cerr << err.what() << '\n'; 
}
*/


It is recommended not to use the std namespace.
Using endl is a bit slow so using '\n' will make your code faster


It's also recommended to not use exceptions this way. As an exercise this is okay, but in real-world code exceptions should not be used for ordinary flow control. They're used when the code that detects the problem can't solve it.

@PeteBecker Sure, but since the OP wants to use try-catch, I wrote the correct form of that code.

Minor detail: throw (/*what ever error you want*/); conflicts with  catch(const char *e). The catch is far too specific. I recommend making both match, and that would mean throwing a pointer to a c-string.

Normally, streams don't have exception mask set by default. But you can set the desired mask manually, to enable triggering exceptions (for example, when failbit gets set), like this:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n{};
    try
    {
        std::cin.exceptions(std::ios_base::failbit);
        std::cout << "Enter value:\n";
        std::cin >> n;
        std::cout << "Got " << n << '\n';
    }
    catch (const std::ios_base::failure& err)
    {
        std::cerr << "Caught " << err.what() << '\n';
    }
}

However, note that if there is some garbage after a valid numeric value in the input, the operator >> will just extract that value and stop (without failing). A failure will occur only if there is no valid numeric value at the beginning (ignoring whitespace).
